# Updating a bound datatable in Excel using VSTO is slow

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, datatable, vsto

I have an Excel VSTO application that stores a large datatable in memory, and binds a portion of this to a sheet.  Users can change the fields they choose to display, and periodically do a mass update.

The mass update loops through the datatable updating a couple of fields.  This update process seems very slow (ie. updating 40 odd records can take 20 seconds).

The datatable is quite large (10,000 rows by 450 columns) and is bound to both a hidden sheet, and a smaller view (20 fields) bound to a visible sheet.

All updates to the datatable are done in code.

```
ProductRow = dt.Rows.Find(foundRows(i)("Primary Key"))
If IsNothing(ProductRow) = False Then
          ProductRow("DECISION") = "Some Value"
          Updated += 1
End If
```

I suspect its just the large amount of data that is bound to the worksheets which slows this process down, however any suggestions to speed this up are most welcome.

Comment: Is Open XML(https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) an option? It will remove the overhead of the COM layer with the Interop libs. I have not seen any comparisons out there, but it is likely to be TONS faster for something like this. The COM layer is a larger culprit than the file size.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "binds a portion of this to a sheet" and how you accomplish that?  I do not use VSTO, but do use Excel interop.  Searching VSTO bind to worksheet, leads me to believe that this is basic interop to read/write values and not something more complex.  People often code this read/write in the most costly manner, so seeing that code would be useful.  Also, patterns like `ProductRow("DECISION")` may appear innocent, but it requires a string lookup to find the index of "DECISION" each time it executes; instead lookup the index once and use that value instead.

Comment: Hi JamieMeyer.  I'll have to look at Open XML.  I hadn't considered it as an option.  Unfortunately, this is an application hosted within Excel so I'm sort of stuck with the COM layer.  I'm using VSTO and non-com code where I can but I think its the fact I'm working within Excel that makes some of this stuff slow.

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn.  VSTO has native functionality to bind a datatable to a worksheet.  This means any updates to the datatable are immediately reflected in the worksheet, and you can determine what fields are shown.  For example, in this application, there are over 400 fields and we allow users to choose what they want to show which is generally about 20.

Comment: Just another quick comment that I mentioned below.  I turned screen updating off for the process and this had a massive performance increase.  I think each record change prompted Excel to update the bound worksheets - as these are large, the operation took time.

Answer (score 0):

Using VSTO to loop through a spreadsheet is going to be slow in almost any event with that many rows/columns.  Even VBA would not be that good at the task.

I'd recommend you implement a poor-man's state model.  In other words, add a column (hidden if necessary) to indicate the state of each row -- specifically if it's been changed or not.  When any change is made, make sure the column for the row's state is updated to show that the row has been altered.  You can do this through the worksheet change event if you don't already have a means to accomplish this.

Then, when you loop through the spreadsheet, focus only on values whose state has been changed.  My guess is you are checking and updating every row, even those that don't need to be updated.

As a final thought, does this have to be done in Excel?  The databinding in a standard .NET grid would handle this almost out of the box.

Comment: Hi Hambone.  When I setup the datatable, I designated the field "Primary Key" as the Primary Key.  The code above should just find that one record?  I do maintain a list of edited records in a manner similar to what you suggested.  Even so, looping through the 40 odd changes takes a while.

Comment: One thing I tried which has made a difference is turning off screen updating.  I think this might be the culprit.  As the datatable is bound, I think the screen updates for each record change.  Turning screen updating off for the process has made a big difference.

Comment: And I would LOVE to develop this as an application, not an Excel Addin, however that's what the users desperately want :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I understand -- users are very enamored with Excel.  I didn't think about screen updating; that's a great idea.  I actually recommend you post that as an answer (answer your own question) and mark it as accepted; I'd vote for it -- that will help others in the future who might have a similar issue.  If you add `interop` to your tags that will help people who have the issue find it.